# How can I get data from a specific class of a html tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I want to get data located(name, city and address) in `div` tag from a HTML file like this:

```
<div class="mainInfoWrapper">
    <h4 itemprop="name">name</h4>
    <div>
        <a href="/Wiki/Province/Tehran"></a>
         city
        <a href="/Wiki/City/Tehran"></a>
         Address
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how can I get data that i want in that specific tag.
obviously I'm using python with `beautifulsoup` library.

Comment: i get the name but doing some thing like this:
**name_b = soup1.find('h4')
for child in name_b.children
name = child**

h4 only used once in that page but there are many div tag with no special id  and I don't know how i have to access them.

Comment: Can you show how the multiple `div`s are structured, it will affect the answer.

Comment: you can see the web that I scraping here:
http://goo.gl/sCXNp2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several `<h4>` tags in the source HTML, but only one `<h4>` with the `itemprop="name"` attribute, so you can search for that first. Then access the remaining values from there. Note that the following HTML is correctly reproduced from the source page, whereas the HTML in the question was not:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="mainInfoWrapper">
    <h4 itemprop="name">            
        NAME
        &nbsp;                          

    </h4>                           
    <div>                           
        <a href="/Wiki/Province/Tehran">PROVINCE</a> - <a href="/Wiki/City/Tehran">CITY</a> ADDRESS
    </div>                          
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
name_tag = soup.find('h4', itemprop='name')
addr_div = name_tag.find_next_sibling('div')
province_tag, city_tag = addr_div.find_all('a')

name, province, city = [t.text.strip() for t in name_tag, province_tag, city_tag]
address = city_tag.next_sibling.strip()
```

When run for the URL that you provided

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://goo.gl/sCXNp2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
name_tag = soup.find('h4', itemprop='name')
addr_div = name_tag.find_next_sibling('div')
province_tag, city_tag = addr_div.find_all('a')

name, province, city = [t.text.strip() for t in name_tag, province_tag, city_tag]
address = city_tag.next_sibling.strip()

>>> print name
بیمارستان حضرت فاطمه (س)
>>> print province
تهران
>>> print city
تهران
>>> print address
یوسف آباد، خیابان بیست و یکم، جنب پارک شفق، بیمارستان ترمیمی پلاستیک فک و صورت
```

I'm not sure that the printed output is correct on my terminal, however, this code should produce the correct text for a properly configured terminal.

Comment: i tried name = div_tag.text.split()
and I get this result:

[u'\u0628\u06cc\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646', u'\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646\u067e\u0627\u0631\u0633', u'\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646', u'-', u'\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646', u'\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646\u067e\u0627\u0631\u0633\u060c', u'\u0646\u0628\u0634', u'\u0641\u0644\u06a9\u0647', u'\u0633\u0648\u0645', u'\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646\u067e\u0627\u0631\u0633']

Comment: @Mehdi : I have update my answer. You haven't reproduced the source HTML correctly when you attempted to summarise it for your question. The province and city values are _children_ of the `<a>` tags, not siblings. The address is a sibling of the `<a>` tags. Also there is more than one `<h4>` tag, but fortunately only one with the `itemprop="name"` attribute.

Comment: It works correctly and give me exactly what I want! :)
But because I'm new to beatifulsoap and of course ptyhon , i cant understand what happen in line that name , province and city got value?

Comment: That's called list/tuple unpacking. The RHS is a list comprehension that iterates over each of the tags and gets its text. This creates a list of 3 items (the tag's text) which are then unpacked into variables name, province and city. It is equivalent to these separate assignments: `name = name_tag.text.strip()`, `province = province_tag.text.strip()` and `city = city_tag.text.strip()`. Address is a special case, so it can not use the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with built-in `lxml.html` module :

```
>>> s="""<div class="mainInfoWrapper">
...     <h4 itemprop="name">name</h4>
...     <div>
...         <a href="/Wiki/Province/Tehran"></a>
...          city
...         <a href="/Wiki/City/Tehran"></a>
...          Address
...     </div>
... </div>"""
>>> 
>>> import lxml.html
>>> document = lxml.html.document_fromstring(s)
>>> print document.text_content().split()
['name', 'city', 'Address']
```

And with `BeautifulSoup` to get the text between your tags:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> print soup.text
```

And for get the text from a specific tag just use `soup.find_all` :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_HTML_source)
for line in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "mainInfoWrapper"}):
    print line.text
```

Comment: thanks Kasra , my  code is a part of bigger HTML document, but I only want some specific text that i wrote them in the question

Comment: @Mehdi Welcome,in that case just use `find_all`.

Answer (score -1):

If h4 is used only once then you can do this -

```
name = soup.find('h4', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'})
print name.text
parentdiv = name.find_parent('div', class_='mainInfoWrapper')
cityaddressdiv = name.find_next_sibling('div')
```